# postgresql - data divided by months

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2

I have following tables

[image] and [image]

I receive the Count of user_id per month where the registration date and login date should be different. For example :
[image]

However, I need to receive the count of unique users like the below example:

[image]

where yellow cells are registration count per month. The others data are unique_user that login in the next months which are different from registration.

For instance user_ID 104 made a registration on Mar and had to login in Mar, Apr and May. I need to see logins after Mar and divided by months

As a conclusion I need to see all unique users that has a login in months after registration month.

```
registration table      
User_ID month   registration_date 
101 dec 12.12.2016
102 dec 1.12.2016
103 feb 2.2.2017
104 mar 14.3.2017
105 mar 14.3.2017
106 apr 5.4.2017
107 may 15.5.2017
108 may 17.5.2017
109 may 18.5.2017
```

---

```
login table     
user_id month   login_date
101 dec 12.12.2016
101 jan 1.1.2107
103 apr 1.4.2017
101 may 1.5.2017
104 mar 14.3.2017
104 mar 15.3.2017
104 apr 1.4.2017
104 may 5.5.2017
105 may 15.5.2017
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: I read it, but this is only data for example ... i made it in excel for clear explanation

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you need to write something like following to get what you need:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, reg.month reg_month, reg.month log_month
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, month) month
  FROM registration_table
) reg 
GROUP BY reg.month
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, reg_month, log_month
FROM (
  SELECT reg.month reg_month, log.month log_month FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, month) user_id, month
    FROM registration_table
  ) reg
  JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, month) user_id, month
    FROM login_table
  ) log ON log.user_id = reg.user_id AND log.month != reg.month
) sub
GROUP BY reg_month, log_month
```

1. First you should fill your table with 0 values for each cell because that query doesn't iterate through each month.
2. Then just execute query and for each cell (reg_month, log_month) fill corresponding `cnt` value.

I create following [sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2e52e/16) for you. It fills table correct with your input/output example.

Just a few notes.

- Your tables data should be valid. E.g. no login data for not already registered user.
- Not included year processing.

Comment: Thanks man, Your script was very useful, I changed, but logic was great! Thanks again!

Comment: @DejanIvanov glad to help you.